# link with hash (anchor) react-router with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, anchor

I need link to page with anchor (scroll to element).
I try this:

1. `<Link to="link#anchor" />` - error: no route
2. `<Link to={{ pathname: "link", hash: "anchor" }} />` - typescript error
3. `<Link to="link" hash="anchor" />` - warning: Unknown prop `hash` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element

How i can do it?

```
react-router@3.0.2
```